# Hashing_trick in Keras. How it works?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Needs basic understanding of one hot or hashing trick in keras.

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import hashing_trick
from keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence
# define the document
text = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog dog.'
# estimate the size of the vocabulary
words = set(text_to_word_sequence(text))
print(words)
vocab_size = len(words)
print(vocab_size)
# integer encode the document
result = hashing_trick(text, round(vocab_size*1.3), hash_function='md5')
print(text)
print(result)
```

Output:

{'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog', 'quick', 'brown', 'jumped', 'fox'}
8
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog dog.
[6, 4, 1, 2, 7, 5, 6, 2, 6, 6]

Conclusion:
Each tokens are assigned an integer here. For eg.
"quick is assigned 4"
the--6 
quick--4
brown--1
fox--2
jumped--7
over--5
the--6
lazy--2
dog--6

I would like to understand how "the" & "dog" are assigned same integer 6.
Correct me if I am wrong & please provide explanation how it does exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a [hashing collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution).  The hash function is just a function computed on the input words.  For example, Java's default hash function does something like multiplying the first character by 1, the second character by 31, the third character by 31^2, etc., and adding them all together.

There is no guarantee that two different strings might not compute the same number.

This problem becomes even more pronounced if we choose a small vocabulary size.  If the vocabulary size is 10, for example, a hash of 11 might "wrap around" to 1. (A modulus operator is applied to map an arbitrarily-large integer into the range 1-`vocab_size`.)

If you want to make hashes unlikely, using `vocab_size = 10*len(words)` or `vocab_size = 10*len(words)` could reduce the number of collisions.

I'm not sure what the cost of a larger vocabulary is downstream, however.